# Wireshark on CentOS does not start

Tags: linux, networking, centos, wireshark

I'm using CentOS 6.4 64bit.

When I run wireshark i get the following error:

> No protocol specified
>
> (wireshark:3620): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0

It has come to my attention that when I disable the network (clicking on the icon in the top right corner and clicking 'disconnect'),wireshark runs with no error. But then when I re-enable the network again, I get the same error.

Comment: Are you running Wireshark from the command line, or from the GUI (double-clicking, menu item, etc.)?  If it's from the command line, what's printed if, for example, you run `xterm` from the command line?

Comment: I want to run it GUI mode.
-bash: xterm: command not found